# Some algebra questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The polynomial $p(x) = (2m-1)x^2+(m+1)x+(m-4)$ can be written as a perfect square. Find the value(s) of $m$.
Okay let's first divide by $2m-1$ to get $$x^2+\frac{m+1}{2m-1}x+\frac{m-4}{2m-1}$$ and we know this is then of the form $p(x) = x^2+bx+c$ which is a monic quadratic so $$p(x) = x^2+bx+c = (x+\frac{1}{2}b)^2+k,$$
where $k = c-\frac{b^2}{4}$. How would we get $m$ from this?
One root of the equation $x^2+px+q = 0$ is $n$ times the other, where $n \neq 0$. Show that $qn^2+(2q-p^2)n+q = 0$. Using the quadratic formula we have $$x = \frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}.$$ What do we do next? Thanks for your help.

Comment: (i) What have you tried? (ii) This does not look like linear algebra. Why are you tagging it “linear algebra”? What is your assignment that you are quoting, and what is *your* question, *your* words, *your* work? You’ve been on the site for a year. You should be familiar with how questions that show no work and no context are received.

Comment: HINT: A quadratic is a perfect square if and only if (1) it’s leading coefficient is a square; and (2) it has a repeated root.

Comment: Forget making it monic.  $ax^2 + bx + c$ is a perfect square if $b^2-4ac = 0$

Comment: Great thank you. I got $m=5$. Which gives us $p(x)=(3x+1)^2$.

Comment: @Doug so $2x^2+4x+2$ is a perfect square? Depends what ring you're working over, I guess.

Comment: The given polynomial, contrary to what you stated, cannot be written as a perfect.  We're you attempting to ask for which values of m is p(x) a perfect square?

Comment: Yes I was indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial $p(x)=(2m-1)x^{2}+(m+1)x+m-4$ 
can be written as a perfect square when it is equal to

$$(A x+B)^{2}$$

therefore, this implies that

$$(2m-1)x^{2}+(m+1)x+m-4=A^{2}x^{2}+2A B x+B^2$$

i.e.

$$x^{2}(A^{2}-2m+1)+x(2A B-m-1)+B^{2}-m+4=0$$

so it must appear that

$A^{2}-2m+1=0$

$2A B-m-1=0$

$ B^{2}-m+4=0$

simultaneously.

Resolving the system results in the following values:

$m=5, A =+3, B =+1;$

$m=5, A = -3, B =-1;$

$m= \frac{3}{7}, A=+\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{7}, B = - \frac{5i \sqrt{7}}{7};$

$m= \frac{3}{7}, A=-\frac{ i\sqrt{7}}{7}, B = +\frac{5i \sqrt{7}}{7}.$